# CentOS 7 Why does the beep package not exist?

Tags: centos, terminal

I am not able to find the fabled 'beep' package using a `yum search`.

How can I make a *beep* on my system from the terminal without the package?

`echo '\a'` does not work either.

Comment: Did you try `echo -e "\a"`

Comment: Ah, I should mention that I am using SSH and that only "beeps" my computer.

Comment: I've replaced "module" with "package" in your question because module implies kernel module; what you're looking for is a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accounting for the comment that `echo` *only "beeps" my computer*, the question is not looking for a way to use `echo` (or `tput bel`), but for something like that mentioned in *[Remotely make the computer beep on built-in speaker](https://superuser.com/questions/47564/remotely-make-the-computer-beep-on-built-in-speaker)*.

That wouldn't be in the standard CentOS repositories since it is not in Red Hat Enterprise.  But there is a package for it on [RepoForge](http://repoforge.org/), as shown here:

- http://pkgs.repoforge.org/beep/, e.g.,
- http://pkgs.repoforge.org/beep/beep-1.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm

You could either just download the package and install it using `yum`, or configure your system to add RepoForge's repository (and install it just like any other package).

Comment: Here's a mirror if anyone is interested. – https://centos.pkgs.org/7/repoforge-x86_64/beep-1.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm.html